# why the first null will not get by split function?

Tags: javascript, regex

There a split function with javascript:

```
"ff4400".split(/(?=((?:..)+$))/)
```

while i think the result will be:

```
["", "ff4400", "ff", "4400", "44", "00", "00"]
```

but it not:

```
["ff", "4400", "44", "00", "00"]
```

as you can see, in fact, the delimiters are "4400", "00", but I think it should be "ff4400", "4400", "00". ps: the captured elements will be in array.

Comment: you are not clear can you please elaborate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are rightly puzzled because that's how things should turn out based on just the regex. However, [`String.prototype.split`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.5.4.14) introduces some quirks of its own:

> The value of separator may be an empty String, an empty regular
>   expression, or a regular expression that can match an empty String. **In
>   this case, separator does not match the empty substring at the
>   beginning** or end of the input String, nor does it match the empty
>   substring at the end of the previous separator match.

The regex used here will only match empty strings, so the match that corresponds to the beginning of the string is discarded and the elements it would have produced in the result (`""`, `"ff4400"`) are missing.

Comment: I had understood, thanks. in fact, if the regexp match a empty string, it will discard the beginning or end of the string. For example: "ab".split(/^|$/) will get ["ab"] , but ",ab,".split(/,/) will get ["", "ab, ""]